# how to execute multiple tests on multiple items with py.test

Tags: python, pytest

I'm a novice in python and also in py.test.  I'm searching a way to run multiple tests on multiple items and cannot find it.  I'm sure it's quite simple when you know how to do it.

I have simplified what I'm trying to do to make it simple to understand.

If I have a Test class who defines a serie of tests like this one :

```
class SeriesOfTests:
    def test_greater_than_30(self, itemNo):
        assert (itemNo > 30), "not greather than 30"
    def test_lesser_than_30(self, itemNo):
        assert (itemNo < 30), "not lesser thant 30"
    def test_modulo_2(self, itemNo):
        assert (itemNo % 2) == 0, "not divisible by 2"
```

I want to execute this SeriesOfTest on each item obtained from a function like :

```
def getItemNo():
    return [0,11,33]
```

The result i'm trying to obtain is something like  :

```
RESULT : 
Test "itemNo = 0"
  - test_greater_than_30 = failed
  - test_lesser_than_30 = success
  - test_modulo_2 = success

Test "itemNo = 11"
  - test_greater_than_30 = failed
  - test_lesser_than_30 = success
  - test_modulo_2 = failed

Test "itemNo = 33"
  - test_greater_than_30 = success
  - test_lesser_than_30 = failed
  - test_modulo_2 = failed
```

How can I do this with py.test?

Than you guys (and girls also)

André

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Forget about the previous answer. Given that you **need** the tests to be grouped by value, you can use [scenarios](https://docs.pytest.org/en/stable/example/parametrize.html#a-quick-port-of-testscenarios). I've just adapted the example from the docs:

```
import pytest

def pytest_generate_tests(metafunc):
    idlist = []
    argvalues = []
    for scenario in metafunc.cls.scenarios:
        idlist.append(scenario[0])
        items = scenario[1].items()
        argnames = [x[0] for x in items]
        argvalues.append(([x[1] for x in items]))
    metafunc.parametrize(argnames, argvalues, ids=idlist, scope="class")

scenario1 = ('itemNo = 0', {'itemNo': 0})
scenario2 = ('itemNo = 11', {'itemNo': 11})
scenario3 = ('itemNo = 33', {'itemNo': 33})

class TestSeries:
    scenarios = [scenario1, scenario2, scenario3]
    
    def test_greater_than_30(self, itemNo):
        assert (itemNo > 30), "not greather than 30"
    def test_lesser_than_30(self, itemNo):
        assert (itemNo < 30), "not lesser thant 30"
    def test_modulo_2(self, itemNo):
        assert (itemNo % 2) == 0, "not divisible by 2"
```

And the output is:

```
$ py.test -v
============ test session starts ==============================================
platform linux2 -- Python 2.7.4 -- pytest-2.4.2 -- /home/jose/.virtualenvs/pytest1/bin/python
collected 9 items 

test_first.py:23: TestSeries.test_greater_than_30[itemNo = 0] FAILED
test_first.py:25: TestSeries.test_lesser_than_30[itemNo = 0] PASSED
test_first.py:27: TestSeries.test_modulo_2[itemNo = 0] PASSED
test_first.py:23: TestSeries.test_greater_than_30[itemNo = 11] FAILED
test_first.py:25: TestSeries.test_lesser_than_30[itemNo = 11] PASSED
test_first.py:27: TestSeries.test_modulo_2[itemNo = 11] FAILED
test_first.py:23: TestSeries.test_greater_than_30[itemNo = 33] PASSED
test_first.py:25: TestSeries.test_lesser_than_30[itemNo = 33] FAILED
test_first.py:27: TestSeries.test_modulo_2[itemNo = 33] FAILED
```

I think that's the closest you can get.

Comment: Sorry but like I said to falsetru, I want the result to be grouped by itemNo.

Comment: It's more like I want...  Now I just need a way to generate list of scenarios dynamically from the result of my function getItemNo()...

Comment: I will finaly use your answer because it was almost complete and easier to understand...   we just need to replace the scenarios definition with : scenarios = []
    for itemNo in getItemNo():
        scenarios.append(("item no {}".format(itemNo), {'itemNo':itemNo}));

Answer (score 4):

Use [fixture](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/fixture.html):

```
import pytest

@pytest.fixture(params=[0, 11, 33])
def itemNo(request):
    return request.param

def test_greater_than_30(itemNo):
    assert (itemNo > 30), "not greather than 30"
def test_lesser_than_30(itemNo):
    assert (itemNo < 30), "not lesser thant 30"
def test_modulo_2(itemNo):
    assert (itemNo % 2) == 0, "not divisible by 2"
```

**NOTE**: The name of the fixture function (`itemNo`) and the name of the parameter of test functions should be same.

See [Demo run](http://asciinema.org/a/6557).

---

**UPDATE**

```
import pytest

class FunctionWrapper(str):
    def __init__(self, f):
        self.f = f
    def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return self.f(*args, **kwargs)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.f.__name__

def greater_than_30(itemNo):
    assert (itemNo > 30), "not greater than 30"
def lesser_than_30(itemNo):
    assert (itemNo < 30), "not lesser thant 30"
def modulo_2(itemNo):
    assert (itemNo % 2) == 0, "not divisible by 2"

@pytest.fixture(params=[0, 11, 33])
def itemNo(request):
    return request.param

@pytest.fixture(params=map(FunctionWrapper, [
    greater_than_30, lesser_than_30, modulo_2
]))
def assertion_func(request):
    return request.param

def test_item_no(itemNo, assertion_func):
    assertion_func(itemNo)
```

Use `-v --tb=no` option.

For example:

```
============================= test session starts ==============================
platform linux2 -- Python 2.7.5 -- pytest-2.3.5 -- /usr/bin/python
collected 9 items

test_sample.py:26: test_item_no[0-greater_than_30] FAILED
test_sample.py:26: test_item_no[0-lesser_than_30] PASSED
test_sample.py:26: test_item_no[0-modulo_2] PASSED
test_sample.py:26: test_item_no[11-greater_than_30] FAILED
test_sample.py:26: test_item_no[11-lesser_than_30] PASSED
test_sample.py:26: test_item_no[11-modulo_2] FAILED
test_sample.py:26: test_item_no[33-greater_than_30] PASSED
test_sample.py:26: test_item_no[33-lesser_than_30] FAILED
test_sample.py:26: test_item_no[33-modulo_2] FAILED

====================== 5 failed, 4 passed in 0.03 seconds ======================
```

See http://asciinema.org/a/6562

Comment: Sorry, but it's not really the result that I want.  The result must show failure (or success) of each function for an itemNo.  In your example it shows the failure of each itemNo for a function.

Comment: @AndréGodin, I updated the answer. It will give you what you want. (Use `-v --tb=no` option)

Comment: thanks for the effort, but again, your result is not grouped by itemNo.  Is it possible to have it grouped in a way that it will show result of each test method for an itemNo and then continue with the second itemNo and so on?  please refer to my example of result I want

Comment: @AndréGodin, [Here](http://asciinema.org/a/6563) is an alternative that use `pytest.mark.parametrize` and `itertools.product`.

Comment: I must admit that it works...  I just don't understand how it is :)  Thank you falsetru.  Can I ask you to explain it briefly please...  for the novice I am :)